# Which breaker controls the HVAC unit?

Tags: hvac, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, thermostat

I want to inspect the thermostat wiring in my apartment. It's an old White Rodgers so I have to turn off the breaker before removing the thermostat housing.

My apartment has an HVAC unit that looks like this:
[image: Representative image of HVAC in my apartment]

Which breaker controls it?

[image: Breaker panel]

Does the 'heat' breaker control the internal unit in my apartment and the 'ac comp' breaker control the external compressor unit? The name 'heat' threw me off and I'm wondering if it should say 'heat/cool' for the internal unit

My apartment fully uses electric for the dryer and stoves and I don't see gas lines running anywhere either.

Comment: I would guess that the "Heat" (5/7) is the unit you see in the wall, and "A/C-comp" (Air conditioning compressor) in 2/4 is for the compressor, perhaps outdoors? But, I'd flip both of those off just to be sure nothing from the A/C part is still live... Note that a contactless voltage probe is fairly cheap and useful in this situation to see if there is anything live inside the unit.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I'll flip both to be safe. Do I have to wait a bit after setting the thermostat to OFF and then flipping the breakers? Or will the compressor not care when power is cut to it?

Comment: If the A/C is off, it won't care.

Comment: If you don't own the apartment it's not yours to tamper with without landlord permission.  If you do own the apartment there are sharp limits on allowable DIY work, but changing lights, switches, receptacles and thermostats is fair play.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I'll be playing it safe and asking my landlord to install the thermostat. I just needed confirmation on the wiring first to ensure if it was compatible

Comment: @rsn  if your same thermostat controls both heating and A/C, it must be compatible.  *Many* electric-heater thermostats are 240V types... but none of those can control an A/C unit.  A photo of your thermostat would help a lot - model # would be even better.

Comment: You've already got a smart thermostat. Oh, wait, that's a random picture of something off the internet. You took a pic of _your_ actual panel, why wouldn't you also include a pic of _your_ actual furnace install and thermostat? :shrug:

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica its a White Rodgers 1F58W-58. Good ol' mercury thermostat. Most of the appliances in my apartment are older than I am!

Answer (score 4):

5/7 is labeled heat, but heat is actually a furnace of some sort which includes an *air handler*. That air handler is *also* used by the air conditioning on 2/4. To play it safe, turn both 2/4 and 5/7 off.

That being said, "apartment" typically means "rental". In a rental you are limited as to what you can do. Generally speaking, the thermostat and the rest of the HVAC system is provided by the landlord and you are not supposed to change anything about it. "Inspect the thermostat wiring" to me sounds like "I want to put in a fancier thermostat, but to do that I need to check if it has a C wire and what other wires it does/doesn't have". Which your landlord may not appreciate your doing.

On the other hand, if this is a condominium where you actually own everything inside your walls then replacing your thermostat is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Alright thanks. Both breakers did the trick. Anyways, the thermostat does contain a C wire so I'm going to ask my landlord to install a smart thermostat I purchased

Comment: Perfect. That's the way to do it - landlord does installation so there is no "what did you do to the thermostat?" problem but it also doesn't cost the landlord much because you supply the thermostat and, at least in most places, this is low-voltage so the landlord's regular handyman/etc. can install - no need for an actual electrician.

Answer (score 4):

In a rental unit you need permission from the landlord to do any work.  Legally the landlord can make claim to any appliance you install on the building.

To place a smart thermostat, you need to identify which of three classes of thermostat you have.

- Millivolt thermostat - switches sub-1-volt signal coming from a thermocouple on a gas pilot light. Obviously not yours.
- Line Voltage (240V) thermostat - switches pure electric heaters only.  Switches the actual power in the thermostat.  I've never seen one that could switch an A/C unit - also they must be mounted on standard 1-gang junction boxes, so they have that form factor (like a light switch or outlet).
- 24-volt thermostat - this uses a small 24 volt transformer in the furnace to make a low voltage pilot signal. It is then handled in light 4-8 wire thermostat cable up to the thermostat and out to the A/C unit. This works with all types of furnace (electric via a relay; gas via a magnet valve) and is well-suited to control both a furnace and A/C from one thermostat.

The vast majority of smart thermostats are made for 24V systems. The model number would tell.

If it's a 24V system the thermostat may pop off the backing plate quite easily, and you will spot light red, white, green and yellow wires with terminals marked R or Rh and Rc, W, G, Y, and others.  For a smart 'stat you will want to make sure there is a 5th wire, as smart 'stats need local power and will task the spare wire to that.

Comment: Hint: As you figure out what is what label the breaker panel and also the appliance. That saves a lot of time in later years.

Comment: Yeah I know it's a 24 V system and I've replaced a thermostat before. But in this case, I was playing it safe with the breaker labeling.